# Access Canvas From JFrame

Tags: java, swing, canvas, jframe

I am adding a Canvas to my JFrame - or rather, an object that inherits from Canvas - and then I wish to get that Canvas object from the JFrame, cast it to that object that inherits from Canvas, and call a method.  However, when I add my Canvas to the JFrame and check the length of my getComponents array, it remains the same.  Where is my canvas being added, and where can I access it?

```
System.out.println(getComponents().length());  
add(new OuterSpace());
System.out.println(getComponents().length());  //This length doesn't change after I add the Canvas for some odd reason
```

[EDIT]  There is a certain method that I cannot call until the Canvas has been added to a JFrame, so that is why I wish to achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

Your component is being added to the contentPane, which is usually a JPanel and which is held a JLayeredPane held by the JFrame's JRootPane.

More importantly, as I've mentioned previously, don't use sucky code like this. Instead create an OuterSpace variable, assign your instance to the variable, add the variable to the JFrame, and then use the variable when you want to access the instance.

---

Note, this doesn't make sense:

> There is a certain method that I cannot call until the Canvas has been added to a JFrame, so that is why I wish to achieve this.

---

**Edit**

Also check out: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html

---

**Edit 2**
You ask:

> I am getting an error when I do this, because I want to access the bufferstrategy from the canvas, which I cannot do until it's been added to the jframe.

Canvas? You shouldn't even be using Canvas objects with Swing GUI's. Use a JPanel. I've never used a BufferStrategy as I usually do all my drawing including animation inside the JPanel's paintComponent method.

It sounds like you're trying to access a graphics-like object before the component has been rendered, and that has no bearing on when the component is created. My recommendations still stand.

Comment: I am getting an error when I do this, because I want to access the bufferstrategy from the canvas, which I cannot do until it's been added to the jframe.

Comment: Something along the lines of "Component must have a valid peer".

Comment: @TheUnrealMegashark So? As Hovercraft says, create an instance of `OuterSpace`, assign to a variable, add it to the frame and THEN access the `BufferStrategy`. Having said that, you should probably restrict access to the `BufferStrategy` to the instance of `OuterSpace`